# Why do both request and hyperquest start throwing errors with 257 GET requests?

Tags: node.js

We're implementing a node.js server to fetch webpages and assets, often in parallel, and saving them to s3. Seems like a perfect fit for node. FYI we're running node v0.8.25 on aws ebs, as v0.10 is unstable on ebs and we couldn't get it to build reliably.  What's giving us fits however, is good old:

```
Error: connect ECONNRESET
at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:761:19)
```

We started with mikeal's request library, which handles 303's, buffering, and other niceties out of the box.  Now the prototype is done, and we're having trouble scaling it.  At 4 or 5 pages it starts throwing the above error.  We set globalAgents to 1,000, agent (pool for request) to false, and lots of other configuration options. No love.

Then we did some additional research and found Hyperquest by substack.  Streaming is tough, because we don't want to count on the content length header, but would be willing to give it a go if it can scale.  Substack has a nifty test suite that compares request to hyperquest:

Request:

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.write(req.url.slice(1) + '\n');
    setTimeout(res.end.bind(res), 3000);
});

server.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('starting test at ' + (Date.now() - startTime));
    var pending = 100;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var r = request('http://localhost:5000/' + i, {pool: false});
        r.pipe(process.stdout, { end: false });
        r.on('end', function () {
            if (--pending === 0) {
                server.close();
                console.log('ending test at ' + (Date.now() - startTime));
            }
        });
    }
});

process.stdout.setMaxListeners(0); // turn off annoying warnings
```

Hyperquest:

```
var http = require('http');
var hyperquest = require('hyperquest');
var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();


var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.write(req.url.slice(1) + '\n');
    setTimeout(res.end.bind(res), 3000);
});

server.listen(5000, function () {
    var pending = 200;
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        var r = hyperquest('http://localhost:5000/' + i);
        r.pipe(process.stdout, { end: false });
        r.on('end', function () {
            if (--pending === 0) server.close();
            console.log('ending test at ' + (Date.now() - startTime));            
        });
    }
});

process.stdout.setMaxListeners(0); // turn off annoying warnings
```

So far so good.  Hyperquest runs in a little over 3 seconds, request takes 12. Then we set http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 1000 (or pool: false in the request) and they both run in 3.229 seconds for 256 request.

Now here's the real problem and the question:  if you increase the pending requests and the loop to 257 or more, both libraries throw the following error:

```
    stream.js:81
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (http.js:1379:15)
    at Socket.socketCloseListener (http.js:1430:23)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Socket._destroy.destroyed (net.js:358:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:245:9)
```

Given that 256 works, but not 257 there has to be some system config variable that needs to be increased, but I can't find it and need an assist.  ulimit -n is 2048, and ulimit -a is:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 2048
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: The web server is probably hanging up the connection because you're spamming it.

Comment: It actually sounds like a Node bug to me, given that I can reproduce the exact problem (256 works, 257 doesn't) on Mac OS X. Both 0.8 and 0.10.

Comment: @Brandon the web server is running in the same process...

Comment: Okay, bit more info (testing `request` only): if you don't stream (but pass a completion callback), it works fine >256 (tested to 1000).

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm still failing. Can you post the callback you're using?

Comment: @CleanTheRuck sorry, my bad, I forgot to actually check for errors in the callback. It still fails >256 :(

Comment: @CleanTheRuck but it seems that testing over `localhost` might be the problem, at least it is for me. Running the server-part on my Linux machine and the client-part on my Mac works okay >256 (both with callback and streams).

Comment: Nope, still getting it.  Must be a config/system variable somewhere, might be different on your linux box?

Comment: Do `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr` to see file-descriptor usage and `cat /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn` or `sysctl net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog` to check pending connections. Could it be that you are running out of memory on your instance ? Which OS/kernel are you using ?

Comment: I'm on osx 10.8.4.  Max files is set to 1024/65536, maxed out on ram with plenty unused.  We also see this behavior on AWS linux on our EC2 instances.  The workaround seems to be setting http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 200.  It sure seems like all the core node.js folks think using the agent is pure evil though, and seems silly given the reason we went to node in the first place was to handle lots of http requests.